# Pivot table filters (Excel) based on list of values

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot, pivot-table

Let's assume I had a pivot table with a large list of row descriptions/labels (e.g. revenue by product). Now let's say I wanted to filter this list to only include a subgroup of all products, maybe 20-30 products.

Is there a way to set the filter without having to select each of the 20-30 products manually from the list of items? For instance, to have the list of row labels (or products in this case) somehwere in my Excel file and reference it instead of selecting the items by hand?

I'd prefer a solution without having to use VBA. If there's no other way, I'd have to go with that one though...

Comment: Why not add in an extra column to your table with "True" / "False" for if your other column's value is part of that list, then use that new column as your filter?

Comment: This post of mine might help: http://yoursumbuddy.com/filter-pivot-tables-using-source-data-helper-columns/

Comment: The problem is that the source is an OLAP cube that does not permit any calculated field. Then, if I add this column right next to the pivot table, the sums won't work properly even though the filter would show the correct items.

Comment: Given the limitations you describe, maybe this will help: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/